# Use PHP function in TWIG?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In PHP templates I can use php functions, for example:

```
foreach ($users as $user){
  echo someFunction($user->getName());
}
```

How can I make it in TWIG?

```
{% for user in users %}
    * {{ user.name }}
{% else %}
    No user have been found.
{% endfor %}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need are [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) or [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters). You can easily add these using the examples.

Comment: Could you include a bit of details about the implementation? Should the function and the instantiation of the "Twig_Environment" class be included in the controller? Should the object "$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader)" be passed as a variable (e.g. 'twig'=>$twig) to the rendered template? What should be included in the "/path/to/templates" in the definition "$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');". Is that the path to the templates in my bundle? does it need to be absolute? It does not work for me. An example would be most appreciated...

Comment: For anyone coming here and wanting an example, there's a very good and simple example in the Twig documentation at sensiolabs:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: FYI: Links are dead

Answer (score 11):

```
// $twig is a Twig_Environment instance.

$twig->registerUndefinedFunctionCallback(function($name) {
    if (function_exists($name)) {
        return new Twig_SimpleFunction($name, function() use($name) {
            return call_user_func_array($name, func_get_args());
        });
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Function %s not found', $name));
});
```

In a twig template:

```
{{ explode(",", "It's raining, cats and dogs.").0 | raw }}
```

this will output "It's raining". By default, returned values are escaped in Twig.

Twig_SimpleFunction is the preferred class to use. All other function related classes in Twig are deprecated since 1.12 (to be removed in 2.0).

In a Symfony2 controller:

```
$twig = $this->get('twig');
```

Comment: where should be this registered in standard symfony2 app?

Comment: This should never, ever be used as it's terribly insecure.

Comment: Not really, it doesn't suddenly turn into a wordpress. But templates should only render HTML/Javascript using available data.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a Twig extension that lets you call PHP functions form your Twig templates like:

```
Hi, I am unique: {{ uniqid() }}.

And {{ floor(7.7) }} is floor of 7.7.
```

See official [extension repository](https://github.com/umpirsky/twig-php-function).

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in symfony 2 this should also help. Concept is the same but you put the code somewhere else and format it a little differently.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html