# remove file extension from twig variable

Tags: php, twig

I am using Twig, in my template this works for .mp4 extension only

```
{{ video | trim('.mp4', 'right') }}
```

but some files have other extensions like .avi and .mkv
how can I trim the last 4 characters from the {{ video }} variable?

Comment: Edited my answer, you could just use `{{ video|slice(0, (video|length - 4)) }}` to remove the last 4 characters of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this :

```
{{ video | replace({('.' ~ video | split('.')[video | split('.')|length - 1]): ""})}}
```

Look [fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/k2aubp)

Comment: this does it, thank you. 
Not sure how it works yet. 

TWIGFIDDLE whaaaa!!!

Comment: this works, but the array sorting is no longer alphabetical when using {% for video in videos %} <li>{{ video | replace({('.' ~ video | split('.')[video | split('.')|length - 1]): ""})}}</li>{% endfor %}

Comment: silly newb, I fixed with {% for video in videos | sort %}

Comment: @JLeggatt I'm agree with you and personnaly, I prefer Nima's solution :)

Comment: @doydoy44 yeah I didn't want to come across as being against your post, I just think it's right that we try and push the OP to the absolute best solution :)

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own filter for this purpose:

```
// Define a filter using an anonymous function
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('remove_extension', function ($string) {

    // Return file name without extension
    return pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
});

// Add it to twig instance, assuming it is stored in $twig
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Now in your template file you can use `remove_extension` filter:

```
{{ video | remove_extension() }}
```

you can read more about wrigint custom Twig filters here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters

Comment: `return pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME)`

Answer (score 4):

Best way to remove extension is:

```
{{ video | split('.')|slice(0,-1)|join }}
```

This solution:

```
{{ video | split('.')[0] }}
```

should work only when in file name is one dot sign, but when in file name are many dots... this solution does not work.

OR

You can write custom filter in twig and use basename method:

```
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getName()
    {
       return 'twig_extension';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
       return [
           new \Twig_SimpleFilter('basename', [$this, 'basenameFilter'])
       ];
    }

    public function basenameFilter($value, $suffix = '')
    {
       return basename($value, $suffix);
    }
}
```

And use this filter like this:

```
{{ video | basename }}
```

More you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589506/php-basename-twig-equivalent)

Comment: this method just removes the . before the file extension, and leaves the file extension.

Comment: This is the best solution, also its second suggestion. Thank you Krzysztof, and regrets it got ignored...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` :

```
{{ video | split('.')[0] }}
```

This will only work if the string has one `.` in it.

### EDIT

Since some of the strings are going to have multiple `.` in them. I would recommend using the `slice` function:

```
{{ video|slice(0, (video|length - 4)) }}
```

But I would recommend doing this sort of logic on the server before passing it to twig.

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one `.` character in file name.

Comment: there are more than one . so does not work in for this situation.

Comment: Edited the answer, didn't realise your string would have multiple `.` in it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `replace` instead, replacing the characters with nothing.

```
{{ video | replace({'.mp4': ""})}}
```

Comment: your replace example works the same as my original post using trim. I can trim or replace one specified extension.

I need to remove the last for characters or trim/replace from a list of extensions. I have not seen a way to use replace or trim with more than one option.