# Handling a common file between twig and php

Tags: php, twig, slim

I have a site containing both php and twig templates.

I need both systems to use a common `header.php` file that contains php that calls a navigation creating class. I cannot convert the non twig files to twig and I don't see a way to execute the php from within the twig scope.

This is creating a situation where the header file is served incorrectly when used with twig content, as the php is not executed and is displayed to users. I have an extensive and growing set of both Twig and PHP templates (don't ask) - converting one to the other is out of the question.

**Any ideas on how I handle this situation?**

Ohh and this is built on Slim.

**Edit:**

Specifically, this php determines the correct DB connection to use and includes a separate file that decides whether to use a cached version or regenerate the navigation structure from the database.

Not a duplicate - twig functions will not be executed by PHP templates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PHP function in TWIG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180585/use-php-function-in-twig)

Comment: I do not believe so. By using a twig function I would just move the problem into the php based templates instead, since they would not be able to execute it.

Comment: I'm not even sure why you don't use twig for all your output. imho `twig` shouldn't be concerned where it gets it data from.. It just need to receive and display it. Twig should not be responsible to execute any non-output php

Comment: because I'm not in charge of the project

Comment: You should eloborate more then, provide us some of your code you've tried

Comment: Please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264466/twig-template-cannot-include-php-template   What you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Twig is view engine for MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Twig is view template engine for PHP with [Model–view–controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

> The central component of MVC, the model, captures the behavior of the
>   application in terms of its problem domain, independent of the user
>   interface.
>
> - The model directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.
> - **A view can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information are
>     possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for
>     accountants.**
> - The third part, the controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I did solve this. I realized I could distinguish the twig / php source by using the db connection, which allowed me to write a twig function to handle that case and keep the existing php approach for those contexts.

Just for interest, this is the navigation loading code that is now working smoothly:

```
<!-- madness -->
                        <span style="display: none;">{% if 0 == 1 %}</span>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($this->db)) {
                            $pdo = $this->db;

                            require_once 'primary-navigation.php';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <span style="display: none;">{% endif %}</span>

                        <span style="display: none;"><?php if (0 == 1) { ?></span>
                            {{ loadNavigation(pdo) }}
                        <span style="display: none;"><?php } ?></span>

                        <!-- end of madness -->
```

Every line is functional and critical. Count all those languages!